# Is this a possible race condition if both promises resolve concurrently?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise

I have two asynchronous operations:

1. Push a notification to IOS devices.
2. Push a notification to ANDROID devices.
   These two operations are done by two functions which return two different promises. 
   The calling function carrying out these 2 operations need to return only when both the promises are resolved(for simplicity assume these promises are never rejected).

I have written following block of code to accomplish this. When the 'sendIOSPushNotification' promise is resolved, I set a flag saying IOS notification is triggered and check if 'sendAndroidPushNotification' is already resolved, if so resolve the promise(p) from the calling function. 
Similarly check for the state of 'sendIOSPushNotification' promise when 'sendAndroidPushNotification' is resolved.

Ideally one the two promises would resolve first and the promise which resolved last will ensure the calling function promise(p) is resolved. If both 'sendAndroidPushNotification' and 'sendAndroidPushNotification' resolve simultaneously , will it resolve in race condition?

```
function sendNotifs() {
let p = Q.defer();
if (iosDeviceTokens.length > 0) {
    self.sendIOSPushNotification(pUnitObj, alertObj, iosDeviceTokens)
        .then(function () {
            iosNotifAttempted = true;
            if (androidNotifAttempted) { //If promise to send push notification to Android is resolved then resolve 'p'
                p.resolve();
            }
        })
}

if (androidDeviceTokens.length > 0) {
    self.sendAndroidPushNotification(pUnitObj, alertObj, androidDeviceTokens)
        .then(function () {
            androidNotifAttempted = true;
            if (iosNotifAttempted) { //If promise to send push notification to IOS is resolved then resolve 'p'
                p.resolve();
            }
        })
}
return p.promise;
}
```

Comment: It is not possible for two Promise instances to resolve simultaneously. One will happen before the other. Your situation calls for using `Promise.all()` to manage waiting for both Promise resolutions.

Comment: It cannot happen since there is only 1 thread in nodejs applications ;) concurrency is not possible in nodejs :)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: But according to your logic if there is no iOS token or no androud token, the promise will never resolve.

Comment: @pierre yes, JS is observably synchronous, *but* it allows for task-based concurrency (doesn't cause problems in this case, though).

Comment: @JonasWilms : Thanks for finding that out, the promise would have never resolved if both tokens were absent.

Comment: @JonasWilms Could you please explain a bit more about task bases concurrency in JS, i am little new to this.

Comment: Nah, there are already thousands of articles / answers on SO about concurrency in JS / task based concurrency in general. I recommend reading some of them, if there us something unclear feel free to ask a question here on SO (and ping me if needed) :)

Comment: @JonasWilms sure will explore on this :) Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JS is single-threaded.

Concurrency is achieved through the use of event loop and handling the async operations in-between the synchronous code, whenever the CPU is available (totally on-one-foot explanation, but thats the idea).

Your situation invites the use of `Promise.all()`, which operates on an array of promises and resolves only when ALL of them are resolved, or rejected when one of them is rejected.

```
let promises = [];
promises.push(self.sendIOSPushNotification(pUnitObj, alertObj, iosDeviceTokens));
promises.push(self.sendAndroidPushNotification(pUnitObj, alertObj, androidDeviceTokens));
Promises.all(promises).then( () => { /* your code when both are resolved */ } )
```

Comment: The term *framework* doesn't really fit here. Also there is no sense in distinguishing "asynchronous" and "synchronous" when talking on the event loop level, as all the code you write ends up in a task on a taskqueue.

Comment: @JonasWilms got your note about the "frameworks", about the other thing- I know, just tried to make a simple, begginer-friendly explanation :)
Thanks for the markups tho!